# Android web view can't open this site

Tags: android, webview

I searched for Six days for a solution - including all stackoverflow posts and couldn't solve it .

My web view can open sites like Google and Facebook but can't open the site in the code !. I got a blank page ...

here is my full code

```
 webView = findViewById(R.id.wv_pray_time);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://ramadanco.noursal.com/");
        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        // No net error
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            }
        });

        // Pull to refresh
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        webView.reload();
                        if (mySwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

can anyone open this site inside a webview ??

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following things -

1. Very first use the https:// instead of http://.
2. You might be getting the SSL error while loading the content, so you can use it in this way.

   ```
   @Override
       public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
           // ignore ssl error
           if (handler != null){
               handler.proceed();
           } else {
               super.onReceivedSslError(view, null, error);
           }
       }
   ```
3. Check you have added the internet permission

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   ```

Comment: Kindly upvote if the answer is helpful to you. @mahmoud

Comment: I added your (ssl ignoring code) in onCreate like that 
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                if (handler != null) {
                    handler.proceed();
                } else {
                    super.onReceivedSslError(view, null, error);
                }
            }

        });

is this the right way ? because i am still have the same problem ...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use https (which I wouldn't recommend) you also have to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` inside the application tag in the manifest.

Comment: I made it "https" and added this line to application tag in manifest but still have the same problem .. the blank page

Comment: Could you please give some excerpt frim the logcat?